# Modalpopup issue with Frame

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a problem with my modalpopup style when I use frame in my page. I don't get trouble with modalpopup style if I don't use frames in page. Following HTML code and CSS work in normal aspx without a problem. In a page with frame, panel gets top of the page and background colour (grey colour) covers just half of page. And link button goes to right of page. Why does this happen?

CSS style:

```
/* dialog frame */
.modal-dialog
{
    position:absolute;
}

/* dialog contents container */
.modal-dialog .container
{
    font-family:tahoma,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    width:340px;
    border:solid 1px #99aabd;
    background-color:#F2F9FF;
} 

/* dialog header */
.modal-dialog .header
{
    background:url(img/sprite.gif) repeat-x 0px -1100px;    
    height:25px;
    padding-top:5px;
}

/* dialog header message */
.modal-dialog .header .msg
{
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-left:6px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
}         

/* dialog body */
.modal-dialog .body
{
    height:40px;
    background-color:#F2F9FF;
} 

/* dialog body message */
.modal-dialog .body h2
{
    padding-top:10px;
    background-color: #F2F9FF;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:normal;
}  

/* dialog footer */
.modal-dialog .footer
{
    height:30px;
    background-color: #F2F9FF;
} 

/* dialog footer buttons */
.modal-dialog .footer .right
{
    background-color: #F2F9FF;
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:6px;

} 

/* dialog footer checkbox */
.modal-dialog .footer .left
{
    background-color: #F2F9FF;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    padding-bottom:6px;
    padding-left:6px;
} 

/* dialog close */
.modal-dialog .close
{
    right:4px;  
    background: url(img/icons.gif) no-repeat -732px 0px;    
    width:16px; 
    cursor:hand;    
    position:absolute;  
    top:5px;    
    height:16px;
}

/* dialog close hover */
.modal-dialog .close:hover { background: url(img/icons.gif) no-repeat -749px 0px;   }

/* modal overlay */
.modalBackground 
{
    background-color:Gray;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

Page's code. It works properly when I don't use frame:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <div>
    <TABLE id="Table1" style="Z-INDEX: 101; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 685px; HEIGHT: 192px; TOP: 45px; LEFT: 8px"
                cellSpacing="1" cellPadding="1" width="685" border="0">
                <TR>
                    <TD noWrap>
                        <TABLE id="Table2" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="2" width="100%" border="0">
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px; HEIGHT: 6px" noWrap><asp:label id="Label3" runat="server">Personel Tipi</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD style="HEIGHT: 6px" noWrap><asp:dropdownlist id="cboID_PERSONAL_TYPE" runat="server" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:dropdownlist></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px" noWrap><asp:label id="Label1" runat="server" Width="112px"> Personel Name</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD noWrap><asp:textbox id="txtDS_NAME" runat="server" Width="200px" BorderColor="LightSteelBlue" BorderWidth="1px"                                     Height="20px" BorderStyle="Solid"></asp:textbox></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px" noWrap></TD>
                                <TD noWrap>
                                    <asp:checkbox id="chkActive" runat="server" Text="Active"></asp:checkbox></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px" noWrap><asp:label id="Label4" runat="server" Width="112px">Temsilci No</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD noWrap><asp:textbox id="txtTEMSILCI_NO" runat="server" Width="80px" BorderColor="LightSteelBlue" BorderWidth="1px"
                                        Height="20px" BorderStyle="Solid" MaxLength="10"></asp:textbox></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px" noWrap><asp:label id="Label2" runat="server" Width="112px">Director (TSM)</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD noWrap><asp:dropdownlist id="cboID_DIRECTOR" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:dropdownlist></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px" noWrap>
                                    <asp:label id="Label5" runat="server" Width="136px">Expert. (TC)</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD noWrap>
                                    <asp:dropdownlist id="cboID_EXPERT" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:dropdownlist></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px; HEIGHT: 14px" noWrap>
                                    <asp:label id="Label31" runat="server" Width="88px">Type</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD noWrap style="HEIGHT: 14px">
                                    <asp:dropdownlist id="cboID_Type" runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <TR>
                                <TD style="WIDTH: 129px" noWrap>
                                    <asp:label id="Label6" runat="server" Width="88px">Rut</asp:label></TD>
                                <TD noWrap>
                                    <asp:dropdownlist id="cbo_ID_RT" runat="server"></asp:dropdownlist></TD>
                            </TR>
                        </TABLE>
                    </TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD noWrap align="right" style="HEIGHT: 21px"><asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" Width="65px" Text="Save" CssClass="MY_BUTTON"></asp:button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        &nbsp;<asp:button id="btnCancel" runat="server" Width="65px" Text="Delete" CssClass="MY_BUTTON"></asp:button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:button id="btnDelete" runat="server" Width="65px" Text="Sil" CssClass="MY_BUTTON"></asp:button></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD noWrap align="right" height="20"><asp:label id="lblStatus" runat="server" Height="16px" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="True"></asp:label></TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
                    <TD noWrap>

                    </TD>
                </TR>
            </TABLE>
            <asp:label id="Label29" style="Z-INDEX: 103; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 8px; LEFT: 8px" runat="server"
                Width="168px" Height="8px" ForeColor="#0000C0" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt">Parametreler > Bayi ></asp:label><asp:label id="Label30" style="Z-INDEX: 102; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 8px; LEFT: 184px" runat="server"
                Width="200px" Height="8px" ForeColor="#C00000" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt">Personel / Temsilci Girişi</asp:label><asp:textbox id="hdnID" style="Z-INDEX: 104; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 8px; LEFT: 472px" runat="server"
                Width="33px" BorderColor="LightSteelBlue" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="Solid" Visible="False"></asp:textbox>
        <cc1:modalpopupextender ID="mdlDelete" runat="server"
        PopupControlID="pnlDelete"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" OkControlID="btnDeleteOk" CancelControlID="btnDeleteCancel"
        TargetControlID="btnDelete">
     </cc1:modalpopupextender>
      <asp:Panel ID="pnlDelete" runat="server" CssClass="modal-dialog"  style="display:none">
     <div class="frame">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="header">
                            <div class="msg">Warning</div>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CssClass="close" OnClientClick="$find('mdlDelete').hide(); return false;" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <h2>Are u sure?h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <div class="right">
                                    <asp:Button 
                            ID="btnDeleteOk" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="40px" />
                                <input id="btnDeleteCancel" type="button" value="No" style="width:40px" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,i solved my problem.I am migrating my project from 2003 to 2008.I copied my page to 2008,not created new page.So when i create new page in 2008,page runs without problem.

Answer (score 0):

Background color: I assume, that only the Frame will be grey. This is OK, since you should not change HTML Code in another Frame.

Position: The Modal Extender calculates the dialog position. So your CSS values are ignored. Use the Property X and Y on the modalpopupextender to set a fixed position.

```
<cc1:modalpopupextender ID="mdlDelete" runat="server"                                              
    PopupControlID="pnlDelete"  BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"  
    OkControlID="btnDeleteOk" CancelControlID="btnDeleteCancel"
    TargetControlID="btnDelete" X="10" Y="10" />
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer Arthur but it didnt help me.Actually my problem is that  cant click anything when i click the button which is associated with modalpopup.I tried ModalPopup with IFRAME solution but it didnt help me too.U can see this example in the following link.In normal pages,i dont have problem but in IFRAME(which contains my menu) i cant use modalpopup.Maybe i can move Master Page from IFRAME later but i wonder why we cant use modalpopup with IFRAME.IFRAME is common way in web pages to hide static content.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ASPModalInAction.aspx